# Android fragment :How to display nested submenus in onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

My problem is regarding inflating the sub menus graphically.

I have a main menu item:- Settings and Help

Settings has further the  items ->

```
Settings-->Con
        -->Mess
        -->Ale
```

But when I inflate the following xml, On click of Settings the submenu overrides the Settings Menu.Its like the submenu replaces the main menu. But I want to look it hierarchical as shown above.

My menu.xml file is very simple.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_contacts"
                app:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/setup_contacts"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_message"
                app:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/setup_message"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_alert"
                app:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/setup_Alert"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_help" android:title="@string/action_help"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group for that like

```
   <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                android:title="@string/action_settings"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                android:enabled="true"
                app:showAsAction="never"/>

          <group android:id="@+id/floating_group"
                 android:checkableBehavior="single"
                 android:visible="true">
                <item android:id="@+id/menu_contacts"
                      android:title="@string/setup_contacts"
                      app:showAsAction="never"/>

                <item android:id="@+id/menu_message"
                      android:title="@string/setup_message"
                      app:showAsAction="never"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/menu_alert"
                      android:title=""@string/setup_Alert""
                      app:showAsAction="never"/>
          </group>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this...but all items are coming in same list. I want something like start button of windows, where once you place your cursor near an item, its tree opens up. It should look hierarchical showing settings as main option and other three as child of settings.